# Split words to array ignore apostrophe

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of words from a string, but also include the words that include an apostrophe.

This is what I have now:

```
var example_str = "This is an example string that I've created."

function createArr( str ){
    return str.split(/\W+/);
}

 console.log( createArr( example_str ) );
```

It ends up splitting the letters after the apostrophe.

```
["This", "is", "an", "example", "string", "that", "I", "ve", "created", ""]
```

I'd like to return this:

```
["This","is","an","example","string","that","I've","created"]
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9uatwLkg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\W` matches characters that are not `\w`. You can also represent it as a negated character class with `[^\w]`; that makes adding apostrophes easy.

```
return str.split(/[^\w']+/);
```

Since you don’t want the last empty string from the period, either, it might be more appropriate to use a positive match:

```
return str.match(/[\w']+/g);
```

Or even to attempt to exclude common punctuation instead, since there are so many characters that can form parts of words in Unicode (like in “café”):

```
return str.match(/[^\s.,;!?/]+/g);
```

but in that case (since there’s also a lot of punctuation), you may end up grabbing [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and matching [`\p{L}` for all letter characters](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode).

Answer (score 0):

```
var example_str = "This is an example string that I've created."

function createArr( str ){
    return str.split(/[^\w']+/);

}

console.log( createArr( example_str ) );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9uatwLkg/1/)

Comment: A sentence or two of explanation goes a long way toward making what might be a correct answer into a great one.